# Virtual devices for testing alexa smart home skill

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service, alexa-smart-home-skill

I am working on Amazon smart home skill for controlling the smart home appliances. I am done with creating a skill for that. Now I want to test my skill with any type of virtual device. Is there any way (or virtual devices) for testing the smart home skill without using the physical device.

Comment: you can use `simulator`

Answer (score 0):

There's 2 options I use for testing without having physical hardware in front of me.

1. While editing the skill in the developer console (developer.amazon.com) there's a 'Test' tab that allows you to test out your skill and see payloads sent/returned too.
2. There's also a cool online tool called Echoism (https://echosim.io/welcome) that will allow you to log into your Amazon account and interact with Alexa through the browser. To use this you'll need to make sure tests are enabled for the skill through the developer console in your account.

There are also some libraries depending on what language you're writing in that will allow you to test locally without having to deploy to lambda first. If you're using Node.js try out node-lambda (https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-lambda). You can create your own payload and test that against your skill locally. You can also package up your skill, test it and then deploy to lambda via terminal. If you're using Python then try out PythonLambda (https://github.com/nficano/python-lambda). It has the same features as node-lambda.